# Exponential Moving Average Discrepancy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas object. It is an OHLC time-series data-frame.

[image]

I would like to calculate the EMA30 of the `close` column. For that, I used 2 different approaches, just as a test.

```
# Approach A, as explained by sentdex in this video:
# https://youtu.be/t_JXXT7VgeQ?list=PLbLcS9xv6IuGi8uyxMP3-BN-lTRQNpqEG&t=245
def ExpMovingAverage(values, window):
    weights = np.exp(np.linspace(-1., 0., window))
    weights /= weights.sum()
    a = np.convolve(values, weights, mode='full')[:len(values)]
    a[:window] = a[window]
    return a

# Approach B
pd.Series.ewm(local_df['close'].copy(), span=30).mean()
```

Once, calculated I add them into their respective new columns.

```
# EMA30 (Using approach A)
local_df['ema30_a'] = pd.Series.ewm(local_df['close'].copy(), span=30).mean()

# EMA30 (Using approach B)
x = local_df['close'].values
calculate_ema30_b = ExpMovingAverage(x, 30)
local_df['ema30_b'] = calculate_ema30_b
```

The resulting data frame is below:
[image]

However, once plotted, it seems like the pandas (blue) deviates from the other numpy based approaches (red). In that case, which of the calculation methods is the one that is correct?

[image]

Comment: Please share your source data or a simple reproducible example that still illustrates the problem. Ideally anyone can just execute your code and get straight to the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example